# join arrays of object and create new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object like this:

```
 example = [
  {
    id: 1,
    child: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "child 1",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    child: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "child 2",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "child 3",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

and I want to get an array of child objects like this:

```
[{...},{...},{...}]
```

I tired to loop through with map but I'm getting an array of two object.

Comment: Its not clear what you need . Do you need an array of objects with your `child` values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the `child` arrays to a new array and flatten them.

[Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

> The `flatMap()` method returns a new array formed by applying a given
> callback function to each element of the array, and then flattening
> the result by one level. It is identical to a `map()` followed by a
> `flat()` of depth 1, but slightly more efficient than calling those two
> methods separately.

```js
example = [
  {
    id: 1,
    child: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "child 1",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    child: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "child 2",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "child 3",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const newArray = example.flatMap(({ child }) => child);

console.log(newArray);
```